# Silverlight - preventing ChildWindow movement

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, childwindow

Anyone got any neat solutions to prevent a Silverlight ChildWindow being moved?

thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you'd call this neat but...

- Create yourself a new Templated control and call it `ImmovableChildWindow`.
- Modify the class it inherits from to be `ChildWindow`.
- Open Themes/generic.xaml you will find an initial style for the `ImmoveableChildWindow`
- In the Silverlight documentation you'll find the existing template for a ChildWindow at [ChildWindow Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070(VS.95).aspx).
- Note the existing TargetType value for the `ImmovableChildWindow` style.
- Copy'n' paste the whole default style for a ChildWindow from the documentation into your themes/generic.xaml file.
- Replace `TargetType` for this copy to the same value as the exiting `ImmovaleChildWindow` style.
- You can now delete the initial style. Leave only the large copy of ChildWindow style now targeting `ImmovableChildWindow`.
- Find within the `Template` setter change the `TargetType` of to the same value as the style `TargetType`
- Search through the template and find a `Border` with the name **Chrome**.  Delete the `x:Name="Chrome"` attribute.  (This is what we are really after).

Now when you create a new ChildWindow item it will by default inherit form `ChildWindow`, if you want it to be immovable you need modify it to inherit from `ImmovableChildWindow` instead (change the base type in the code-behind and the root tag name in the xaml).

The `ChildWindow` attaches events to the `FrameWorkElement` with the name "Chrome" which enables the child window to be moved about.  However being a well-behaved templated control, if it can't find a `FrameworkElement` called "Chrome" it just continues to work without that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Not Required to Create  new class, instead

1. Copy the style from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070%28VS.95%29.aspx
2. Give `x:key="stylename"`
3. In Construtor of `Childwindow`, paste following code before `InitializeComponent`:

   `this.Style = App.Current.Resources["childWindow"] as Style;`

above solution resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this simple way to do that:
Create a Grid to warp all the content in your ChildWindow.

```
<Grid Margin="0">

<!--Your ChildWindow. Canvas, Grid, Textblock...Whatever-->

</Grid>
```

Since the Grid has a 0 margin, you can not  click it and move it.